# Oracle pivot error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

Hi i've the below query in oracle to get data. it is working fine in sql server, but, when i tried to execute this in oracle it is giving and error.

```
    SELECT PRODUCT, FRED, KATE FROM (
    SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
    FROM Product
    )
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM(QTY) FOR CUST IN (FRED, KATE)
    )
    ORDER BY Product
```

Error:

[image]

and the table o/p is as below

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `SUM(QTY) FOR CUST IN ('FRED' as fred , 'KATE' as kate)`

Comment: thanks buddy, this worked. if you don't mind could you please tell me what happened here. also could you please suggest me any site for learning PIVOT table.? thanks

Comment: @Rakesh unquoted `fred` and `kate` you initially specified were treated as oracle identifiers, though pivot `for` clause required a list of `cust` values to be transposed into columns.

Comment: @Rakesh I guess docs are pretty good: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE